# cannot create autocomplete inside a magnific popup

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, magnific-popup

i can't use the jquery UI autocomplete on magnific popup form. like the below URL. demo URL of jquery UI

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: you tried the ajax function of the magnific-popup? http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax_type

Comment: no it works fine but it shown back side of the popup that mean .ui-autocomplete z-index was zero but the magnific popup z-index value was 1045. if we add z-index for .ui-autocomplete then it shows the values. Thanks @ggzone

Comment: so its a css issue and you found it... alrady fixed it? then close the question or answer it youself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have to add a z-index property to .ui-autocomplete class. in magnific popup the form content z-index property was 1045, so we have to add z-index on .ui-autocomplete class in jqueryui css.